# IE Quirks Mode - border-right not showing up

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border, quirks-mode

I'm designing a navigation bar that HAS to run in IE Quirks mode (i.e. it can't have a DOCTYPE tag at the top).  It also needs to work in Firefox and Safari (quirks mode for safari as well).  My sample right now works in Safari and Firefox.  (View source to see everything, css is in-lined).

My problem is that the border-right doesn't show up in IE!  Any ideas?

[Here is the working sample](http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/border_sample.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not suggesting this is the correct solution but if you remove the background color of rgb(255,255,255) of the #top-nav a style the bar becomes visible in IE - which I guess suggests the hyperlink (in IE's eyes) is overlapping the div border you have defined?

Comment: That certainly makes sense..
I'm going to see if its acceptable to just remove that background and be done with it.. I'll be back with more info shortly.

Comment: Actually all that it needs is a margin around the anchor tag.  Good catch on the background, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For nav use ul tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdVZ6/2/